# Set Video height in HTML5

Tags: html, video, height, width

May be its a simple question but it's really driving me crazy.
I just want to set the height and width of the HTML5 video.

I am using this code:

```
 <video controls="controls" width="1000" id="video">
            <source src="sintel-trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
            <source src="sintel-trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>
```

Result:
[image]

If I add height attribute

```
<video controls="controls" width="1000" height="300" id="video">
                <source src="sintel-trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
                <source src="sintel-trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 </video>
```

Result:
[image]

So am I missing something here?

Can anyone correct the mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried setting the dimensions in CSS instead? Might be easier to tweak them from there.
Also you could set the video to adjust to its parent's size (video { width:100%; height:100%; }) and edit its parent's dimensions on the fly.
Haven't tested it. Just an idea!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't change aspect ratio in `<video>` tag.

However you can read your video content and write it to `<canvas>` element.

For example:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="768" width="1024"></canvas>
```

And JS:

```
function updateVideo( ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    var myVideo = document.getElementById( 'video' );
    ctx.drawImage( myVideo, 0, 0, 640, 480 );
}
setInterval ( updateVideo, 24 );
```

Answer (score 40):

Here is simple CSS trick, you don't need to add any JavaScript or jQuery code. Use `object-fit` CSS property on video tag.

**HTML**

```
<video controls="controls" id="video">
<source src="sintel-trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<source src="sintel-trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

**CSS**

```
#video{
  object-fit: initial;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

[**See Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kab5409f/)

Comment: Never even heard of this property before, had been suffering through oddly positioned video for hours before finding this, thank you

Comment: working for me, +1, i used objest-fit: cover, but this worked.

Comment: i've used object-fit: contain; to solve my problem. but  thanks for the hint.

Answer (score -3):

You can use css to work around.

```
#video {
   width:1000px;
   height:auto;
}
```