# HTML5 video tag incorrect size on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have a .mp4 video file (taken with my iPhone) and I want to show it inside a html5 video tag.

`<video preload="auto" onclick="playpause(this);">
       <source src= <%= encodeURI(post.get("videoFile").url()) %> type="video/mp4">
       Your browser does not support the video tag, that is html5
</video>`

Video plays as expected on Safari and Firefox(after rotating it) but its dimensions on Chrome(Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)) are inverted while its orientation is correct.

[video on chrome; blue box is where the video should be!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GSY7.png)

Setting the dimensions for the video tag did not work.  Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This SO answer worked for me : [CSS property: object-fit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34991048/6502874)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should work by giving the dimensions, don't know why it's acting weird in google chrome. Just try these two snippets if it works for you. And if possible please share the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" style="width:320px;height:240px;" onclick="playPause();" >
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 1st snippet  -->
        <video style="width:320px;height:240px;" controls>
          <source src= <%= encodeURI(post.get("videoFile").url()) %> type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

<!-- 2nd snippet  -->    
       <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src= <%= encodeURI(post.get("videoFile").url()) %> type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
       </video>
```

Comment: I had to keep the preload="auto" and the onclick="playPause();" and none of the snippets worked for me. What seems to do the trick is this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34991048/6502874)